# Minimum vertex cover of given graph

Tags: graph-theory

[image: graph]

I have counted manually the minimum vertex cover to be 21. Is this correct? Is there a systematic way of counting it?

In fact, if I'm not wrong there are only 2 vertex covers of size 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This graph is bipartite, so we know that the size of minimum vertex cover is the same as maximum matching due to [König's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)).

In other words, in bipartite graphs a matching of the same size is a certificate that the vertex cover is minimum. That works also the other way, if we have a matching, then to certify that it is a maximum matching it is enough to show a vertex cover of the same size.

That leads to the following solution **of size 20**:

[image: min vertex cover max matching]

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$